# Соединить текст и число в одну строку питон

Tags: python, случайные-числа, re

хочу сделать шифратор, и хочу сделать формат буква - двухзначное число, но я не могу соединить строки.

```
import random
import re
alfavit = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
num = '1234567890'
def numbers():
   for i in range(33):
      a = random.choice(num)
      b = random.choice(num)
      c = a,b
      print(*c, sep='')
def bukvi():
   res = list(alfavit)
   for i in res:
      i1 = re.sub(r'\s+', '\n', i)
      print(i1)

print (bukvi() + numbers())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать попроще. Диапазон двухзначных чисел (с ведущим нулем) известен - 00..99 (при необходимости его можно настроить аргументами в range(), например `range(10,100)`). Делаем из него список и перемешиваем. В цикле перебираем буквы и соотносим очередную букву с очередным числом. Их "склеиваем" с помощью f-строки. Список шифров возвращаем из функции, распаковываем и печатаем, разделяя переводом строки.

Подход обеспечивает:

- равномерное распределение чисел на буквы;
- уникальность чисел, сопоставленных буквам;
- сохранение порядка следования букв

```
import random
def cipher():
    n = list(range(100))
    random.shuffle(n)
    return [f'{ch} = {n[i]:02d}' for i, ch in enumerate('абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя')]

print(*cipher(), sep='\n')
```

```
а = 63
б = 43
в = 71
г = 02
д = 35
...
ь = 96
э = 67
ю = 33
я = 51
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но если не сложно, можете подробно объяснить 5 строку?

Comment: В f-строках выражения, заключённые в фигурные скобки, вычисляются, и строковое представление результата подставляется вместо групп в фигурных скобках. Также внутри фигурных скобок после двоеточия можно указать формат вывода. Например, :02d - десятичное целое число длиной 2 знака, при необходимости добавлять ведущие нули.

Answer (score 0):

в этой строке ошибка:

```
print (bukvi() + numbers())
```

вот исправленая версия:

```
print (bukvi() + str(numbers()))
```

Comment: Все так же не получается, мне нужно чтобы консоль выводила вот так: а = двухзначное число, а оно в столбик выводит сначала буквы, потом числа

Comment: тогда print (bukvi() +"="+ str(numbers()))